# Imprimir PDF desde 000webhost

Tags: php, html, webservice

Bueno estoy intentando generar un archivo pdf, localmente lo realiza perfecto, pero al subirlo a este host que estoy utilizando de pruebas me sale el sig error;

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Considero que el error no es en el foreach, sino al momento de imprimir los datos en la tabla `td`

```
foreach($sql as $key => $value){ //Linea 71 supuesto error

$html1= <<<EOF
<table style="font-size:13px; padding:5px 10px; border: 1px solid #666;" align="center"> 
<tr>
        <td style="border-right: 1px solid #666; border: 1px solid #666;">$value[nombres]</td>
        <td style="border-right: 1px solid #666; border: 1px solid #666;">$value[apellidos]</td>
        <td style="border-right: 1px solid #666; border: 1px solid #666;">$value[correo]</td>
        <td style="border-right: 1px solid #666; border: 1px solid #666;">$value[usuario]</td>
        <td style="border-right: 1px solid #666; border: 1px solid #666;">$value[privilegio]</td>
</tr>
</table>

EOF;

$pdf->writeHTML($html1, false, false, false, false, ''); //Salida PDF
} //Cierre foreach
$pdf->Output('reporte.pdf', 'I');
```

Comment: Posible duplicado de [FPDF arroja errores en 000webhost](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/105485/fpdf-arroja-errores-en-000webhost)

Comment: el error es al imprimir los datos si remuevo esta parte del `td` `$value[nombres]` y agrego texto html funciona de maravilla

Comment: Si no estoy mal puede ser la ruta del pdf, intenta colocar la ruta completa q te arroja el error

Comment: Por favor verifica el enlace que te coloque es permisos de carpeta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error consiste en dos partes:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in ...

Significa que la variable a recorrer no es "recorrible"

podes chequearla antes asi:

```
if (is_array($sql) || is_object($sql)) {
foreach ($sql as $key=>$value) {
```

la segunda parte del error

> TCPDF ERROR: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file

indica que el navegador recibió algo (texto por ejemplo, el texto del error anterior) antes de poder enviar las cabeceras del pdf

Para saber si la variable/objeto `$sql` tiene datos válidos coloca un `var_dump($sql);` antes del `foreach` y a partir de ahí podrás ver que está sucediendo, puede que localmente `$sql` tenga datos y en el hosting esté vacío.

Comment: me manda ´bool(false)´ como respuesta del ´var_dump($sql)´

Comment: y cuando utilizo el código ´if´ si me aparece el pdf, es decir si se carga, pero no aparece ningún dato de la base de datos.

Comment: entonces el problema está un poco mas atrás, el `$sql` viene vacío por alguna razón, verifica las credenciales en donde haces la conexión (ip/nombre del servidor de base de datos, usuario, password, nombre de base de datos, nombre de la tabla de los datos)

Comment: Efectivamente mi consulta a pesar de que era muy simple (´SELECT * FROM USUARIOS´) en la base de datos la tabla estaba en minusculas, no le tome importancia por lo regular en local me lo corre en mayus o minus, pero en este caso el servidor lo requeria de esta manera (´SELECT * FROM usuarios´)

Comment: Muchas gracias!!